# Why LogCat is full of errors?

Tags: android

I try to make an android app clear of any mistakes and errors. I definitely sure, these are not my mistakes. Of course, there might be different system info messages. But I set the log level to value 'Warn'!!! And after that I still see many strings. They simultaneously fill the log window.

For an example:

```
01-21 20:47:13.336      449-858/? W/SchedPolicy﹕ add_tid_to_cgroup failed to write '15944', len = 5, fd = 34, err = 3
01-21 20:47:13.351  15945-15945/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1424 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2513
01-21 20:47:13.581      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ terminating JDWP 15929 connection: Try again
01-21 20:47:13.722      449-479/? W/SearchableInfo﹕ Invalid searchable metadata for com.quoord.tapatalkpro.activity/.directory.ics.IcsEntryActivity: Search label must be a resource reference.
01-21 20:47:13.753      449-479/? W/SearchableInfo﹕ Invalid searchable metadata for com.quoord.tapatalkpro.activity/.directory.ics.IcsEntryActivity: Search label must be a resource reference.
01-21 20:47:13.816  13402-15966/? W/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads]﹕ [OPTIONAL] Could not find the com.getjar.sdk.rewards.GetJarReceiver defined inside AndroidManifest.xml. It is required if there is no other implementation of Google Play billing.
01-21 20:47:13.826      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ create_local_service_socket() name=shell:am start -n "alexei.androlearn/alexei.androlearn.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
01-21 20:47:13.828  15971-15971/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ adb: unable to open /proc/15971/oom_adj
01-21 20:47:13.874      449-699/? W/SchedPolicy﹕ add_tid_to_cgroup failed to write '15968', len = 5, fd = 34, err = 3
01-21 20:47:13.992      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ create_local_service_socket() name=jdwp:15972
01-21 20:47:13.992      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ looking for pid 15972 in JDWP process list return fds0(24) fds1(25)
01-21 20:47:13.992      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ trying to write to JDWP socket=22 pid=15972 count=1 out_fds=25
01-21 20:47:14.200      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ terminating JDWP 15972 connection: Try again
01-21 20:47:14.223  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 20:47:14.223  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:47:14.230  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 20:47:14.230  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:47:14.242      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ create_local_service_socket() name=jdwp:15989
01-21 20:47:14.242      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ looking for pid 15989 in JDWP process list return fds0(24) fds1(25)
01-21 20:47:14.242      223-223/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ trying to write to JDWP socket=22 pid=15989 count=1 out_fds=25
01-21 20:47:14.378    449-16405/? W/SchedPolicy﹕ add_tid_to_cgroup failed to write '16007', len = 5, fd = 34, err = 3
01-21 20:47:14.476  13402-16012/? W/GetJar SDK [com.zeptolab.ctr.ads]﹕ [OPTIONAL] Could not find the com.getjar.sdk.rewards.GetJarReceiver defined inside AndroidManifest.xml. It is required if there is no other implementation of Google Play billing.
01-21 20:47:14.622      449-449/? W/SchedPolicy﹕ add_tid_to_cgroup failed to write '16021', len = 5, fd = 34, err = 3
01-21 20:47:14.622      449-449/? W/SchedPolicy﹕ add_tid_to_cgroup failed to write '16022', len = 5, fd = 34, err = 3
01-21 20:47:14.868      127-397/? E/hwcomposer_v1.0﹕ [WKR] Timed out waiting for FrameSyncThread...
01-21 20:47:15.493      449-858/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10094
01-21 20:47:15.493      449-858/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10094
01-21 20:47:15.515      449-921/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10094
01-21 20:47:15.515      449-921/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10094
01-21 20:47:15.522    449-13745/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10094
01-21 20:47:15.522    449-13745/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10094
01-21 20:47:39.823      132-444/? W/AudioDigitalControl﹕ GetAfeDigitalStatus mAudioMEMIF[9] state = 1
01-21 20:47:39.930      132-531/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
01-21 20:47:39.931      132-531/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
01-21 20:47:39.931      132-531/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
01-21 20:47:39.937     131-8094/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ parseDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
01-21 20:47:39.937     131-8094/? E/DrmMtkPlugIn﹕ onOpenDecryptSession() : failed to parse dcf file.
01-21 20:47:39.956      132-531/? E/FlvExtractor﹕ [ERROR]:Not an FLV file!!!
01-21 20:47:39.956      132-531/? E/FlvExtractor﹕ [ERROR]:[FLV]mtk_flv_extractor_recognize OUT
01-21 20:47:39.956      132-531/? E/﹕ SniffFLV return 0
01-21 20:47:39.962    132-16042/? E/OMXCodec﹕ @@ [OUT] def.nBufferSize = 32768
01-21 20:47:39.962    132-16042/? E/OMXCodec﹕ @@ [OUT] totalSize = 131584
01-21 20:47:39.967  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/MediatekClassFactory﹕ Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
01-21 20:47:39.968  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException
01-21 20:47:39.968  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at com.mediatek.common.MediatekClassFactory.createInstance(MediatekClassFactory.java:487)
01-21 20:47:39.969  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.initSecureFlag(MediaPlayer.java:1112)
01-21 20:47:39.969  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1091)
01-21 20:47:39.969  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at alexei.androlearn.MediaPlayerTest.onResume(MediaPlayerTest.java:45)
01-21 20:47:39.969  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1190)
01-21 20:47:39.969  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5200)
01-21 20:47:39.969  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2886)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 20:47:39.970  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-21 20:47:39.971  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-21 20:47:39.971  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 20:47:39.971  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn E/MediaPlayer﹕ initSecureFlag() exception
01-21 20:47:50.710    132-18351/? E/AudioMTKHardware﹕ setParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=off"
01-21 20:47:50.749      449-466/? W/MediatekClassFactory﹕ OP not exist!, Get obj from default class
01-21 20:47:51.119      701-710/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.android.launcher/databases/themes.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
01-21 20:47:53.911      132-444/? E/﹕ AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
01-21 20:47:53.911      132-444/? E/﹕ AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
01-21 20:48:04.807      449-466/? E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ Object tried to add another callback
    java.lang.Exception: Called by
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardUpdateMonitor.registerCallback(KeyguardUpdateMonitor.java:1045)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardSelectorView.onResume(KeyguardSelectorView.java:326)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardHostView.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardHostView.java:1070)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardViewManager.java:390)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.handleNotifyScreenOn(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1767)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.access$2200(KeyguardViewMediator.java:108)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator$4.handleMessage(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
01-21 20:48:04.831      132-132/? E/AudioMTKHardware﹕ setParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=on"
01-21 20:48:04.933    449-13745/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.dm/.DMService in 5000ms
01-21 20:48:04.934    449-13745/? W/ActivityManager﹕ skip resumeTopActivityLocked, next = ActivityRecord{41b36cf8 u0 alexei.androlearn/.MediaPlayerTest}
01-21 20:48:05.334      449-698/? W/BroadcastQueue﹕ Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50000010 }
    android.os.RemoteException: app thread has died
        at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.performReceiveLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:386)
        at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.deliverToRegisteredReceiverLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:453)
        at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:670)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:12790)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:375)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1841)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-21 20:48:05.565      542-552/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.android.systemui/databases/quicktool.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
01-21 20:48:05.566      542-552/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.android.systemui/databases/quicktool.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
01-21 20:48:09.969  16086-16086/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 20:48:09.970  16086-16086/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:48:09.971  16086-16086/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 20:48:09.972  16086-16086/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:48:11.679      132-444/? W/AudioDigitalControl﹕ GetAfeDigitalStatus mAudioMEMIF[9] state = 1
01-21 20:48:11.706  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn W/MediatekClassFactory﹕ Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
01-21 20:48:11.710  15989-15989/alexei.androlearn E/MediaPlayer﹕ initSecureFlag() exception
01-21 20:48:11.849      449-858/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41417160 attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@418ac6b0, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41ed7250
01-21 20:48:23.820      132-444/? E/﹕ AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
01-21 20:48:23.820      132-444/? E/﹕ AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
01-21 20:49:00.038    449-13745/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.Battery/.BatteryWidgetService in 5000ms
01-21 20:49:05.058  16136-16136/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:05.058  16136-16136/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:05.059  16136-16136/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:05.060  16136-16136/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:05.110      449-691/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.emailwidget/.UpdateService in 5000ms
01-21 20:49:10.132  16150-16150/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:10.133  16150-16150/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:10.135  16150-16150/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:10.137  16150-16150/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:49:10.232  16150-16150/? W/Email﹕ Application hasn't staret yet
01-21 20:52:10.041      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.043      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.043      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.043      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.044      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.044      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.044      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.045      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.045      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.046      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.047      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.047      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.047      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.048      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.048      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.048      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.049      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.050      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.050      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.050      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.051      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:52:10.051      449-528/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
01-21 20:54:00.070    449-16348/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.usbplugin/.DetectServer in 5000ms
01-21 20:54:05.091  16172-16172/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 20:54:05.093  16172-16172/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:54:05.097  16172-16172/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 20:54:05.103  16172-16172/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:56:10.464      449-633/? W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
01-21 20:57:01.695    449-13745/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.mediatek.atci.service/.AtciService in 5000ms
01-21 20:57:06.715  16186-16186/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 20:57:06.717  16186-16186/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:57:06.719  16186-16186/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 20:57:06.721  16186-16186/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 20:57:39.566      449-514/? W/NetworkStatsRecorder﹕ unknown interfaces [p2p0], ignoring those stats
01-21 20:57:39.566      449-514/? W/NetworkStatsRecorder﹕ unknown interfaces [p2p0], ignoring those stats
01-21 20:57:39.576      449-514/? W/NetworkStatsRecorder﹕ unknown interfaces [p2p0], ignoring those stats
01-21 20:57:39.582      449-514/? W/NetworkStatsRecorder﹕ unknown interfaces [p2p0], ignoring those stats
01-21 20:58:10.792  16186-16198/? E/ATCIJ﹕ Couldn't find 'atci-serv-fw' socket after 16 times, continuing to retry silently
01-21 20:59:32.413  13118-13711/? E/CMC->NioClient3﹕ NioClient thread get exception e: I/O exception while read message:
01-21 20:59:32.414  13118-13711/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.stopService:1430 android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:455 com.asus.cm.push.PushUtil.stopPushService:33 com.asus.cm.push.NioClient3.run:111 <bottom of call stack>
01-21 20:59:32.420  13118-15189/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.stopService:1430 android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:455 com.asus.cm.push.PushUtil.stopPushService:33 com.asus.cm.push.NioClient3.run:111 <bottom of call stack>
01-21 21:01:27.446  13118-13118/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1424 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.asus.cm.push.PushUtil.startPushService:27 com.asus.cm.push.PushControlReceiver.onReceive:54
01-21 21:06:10.472      449-633/? W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
01-21 21:06:10.512    449-16405/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.mediatek.batterywarning/.BatteryWarningService in 5000ms
01-21 21:06:15.526  16228-16228/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 21:06:15.527  16228-16228/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:06:15.528  16228-16228/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 21:06:15.529  16228-16228/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:07:40.453      449-470/? W/BatteryStatsImpl﹕ Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
01-21 21:09:30.788      449-922/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.pl/.parentlock.ParentLockService in 5000ms
01-21 21:09:35.811  16243-16243/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 21:09:35.813  16243-16243/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:09:35.816  16243-16243/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 21:09:35.818  16243-16243/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:10:00.095    449-12873/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.davinci.SNS/.service.BuddyBuzzService in 5000ms
01-21 21:10:05.115  16256-16256/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 21:10:05.117  16256-16256/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:10:05.120  16256-16256/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 21:10:05.123  16256-16256/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:10:05.511  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ rto value is too small:0
01-21 21:10:06.124  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ RRException [mExceptionCode=7, mExceptionMsg=API请求超出配额（7）, mExceptionDescription=null]
01-21 21:10:06.127  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ at com.renren.mobile.rmsdk.oauth.beanrequest.BeanRequest.request(BeanRequest.java:140)
01-21 21:10:06.127  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ at com.renren.mobile.rmsdk.core.RMConnectCenter.request(RMConnectCenter.java:571)
01-21 21:10:06.127  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ at com.renren.mobile.rmsdk.core.RMConnectCenter$2.run(RMConnectCenter.java:593)
01-21 21:10:06.128  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-21 21:10:06.128  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-21 21:10:06.128  16256-16272/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
01-21 21:12:00.046     449-1759/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.ephoto/.data.DataObserveService in 5000ms
01-21 21:12:05.067  16282-16282/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
01-21 21:12:05.070  16282-16282/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:12:05.073  16282-16282/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
01-21 21:12:05.077  16282-16282/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
01-21 21:16:10.479      449-633/? W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

Comment: Every modern os is very chatty and full of irrelevant-to-the-user errors/warnings.

Comment: according to your messages you can see which app or part is causing errors, like @MarcB said there are a lot of logs from other irrelevant stuff for you

Comment: These are not errors that you are need to be concerned about. These just logs from the apps and Android OS.

Comment: Add a filter which only shows the warnings of your app..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a LogCat Filter to only show messages from your own app.  Here's a simple example that limits by my app package and by log level:

[image: my app filter example]

As you can see in the example, though the total number of LogCat messages is 4908, only one of them is from my application.