# Android error "Enter GetCurrentOP"

Tags: android, runtime-error

Since i've started do develop an android app, i 've seen this message. Nut now my log in android stuido is full of this message: "Enter GetCurrentOP". What does this mean?

Comment: this question already has an answer:       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267398/why-logcat-is-full-of-errors

Comment: there is unfortunately only describes how to hide the error . that's not what I'm looking for. I am using the filtering system familiar, but i want to know what this error means. every day this messages become more.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a LogCat Filter to only show messages from your own app. Here's a simple example that limits by my app package and by log

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfjlw.png